rplidar_companion node does not publish to /scan topic
I used the  sudo apt install ros-humble-rplidar-ros and the git https://github.com/allenh1/rplidar_ros
however after building it and sourcing the workspace when i use the launch command.
i look at the ros2 topic info /scan. no publisher.
When i downloaded it before it worked and the rqt graph showed it published to the /scan.
but now it does not.
does some know how to fix this problem?
